# Clear edittext focus and hide keyboard when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, focus, android-edittext

I'm making an app with edittext and a button. When I enter something into edittext and then click a button, I want the keyboard and focus on edittext to disappear but I can't seem to do it.

I inserted these 2 lines of code in XML:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I also tried to add this in the button click method:

```
edittext.clearFocus();
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

And it just won't work, after I press the button, the keyboard remains there and edittext still has focus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

another solution is, create a dummy layout

```
<!-- Dummy item for focus at startup -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dummy_id"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

and set the focus in your `onButtonClickFunction`

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dummy_id)).requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 17):

To hide the keyboard call this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

You can also check this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587937/786337

Answer (score 2):

First you must disable the keyboard:

```
void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
   View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
   InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   assert manager != null && view != null;
   manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Second clear view (Layout, EditText...)focus:

`view.clearFocus`

Answer (score 1):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
editText.setText("");
```

Add the following on your button onclick event

You need to `import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager`;

The keyboard hides and clears the text when you click the button.